# Redshift table grows from 15GB to 185GB just from adding DistKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table with 130 million records. A straight dump of the data into an unindexed table is 15GB. When I dump that table into a table of the same structure but with a distribution key, the table grows  to 185GB. I do not see anything like this in AWS documentation. Is this a compression issue?

```
CREATE TABLE mongousages_withkey
(
   serialnumber      varchar(56),
   "run date"        date,
   "run usage id"    char(1016),
   datetime          varchar(37),
   alteryxversion    varchar(16),
   guid              varchar(40),
   "tool name"       varchar(258),
   "tool count"      float8,
   email             char(256),
   "last load date"  date
)
sortkey(serialnumber);
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail about your table DDL for me to give you a solid answer. 

Comment: @JoeHarris Edited the post with the DDL. Serialnumber is an email address(don't ask).

Comment: Have you got compression on at all? Did you do your `COPY` with `COMPUPDATE ON` included? Is this DDL the before or after DDL? You mention a `DISTKEY` but the DDL only has a `SORTKEY. :)

Comment: @JoeHarris I loaded the table using an insert statement from a base table with no keys, so didn't use COPY. I tried a distkey and sortkey on the same column separately and together and got the same result with all, 185K blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift automatically applies compression to **new** tables when you `COPY` data in the first time. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Loading_tables_auto_compress.html

You didn't specify compression on the version you loaded using `INSERT` so you have **no compression** on it.

Run `ANALYZE COMPRESSION mongousages_withkey;` and create a new table based on the suggested encodings. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mongousages_withkey (
    serialnumber      VARCHAR(56)  NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,"run date"        DATE         NULL ENCODE runlength
   ,"run usage id"    CHAR(1016)   NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,datetime          VARCHAR(37)  NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,alteryxversion    VARCHAR(16)  NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,guid              VARCHAR(40)  NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,"tool name"       VARCHAR(258) NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,"tool count"      FLOAT8       NULL ENCODE delta
   ,email             CHAR(256)    NULL ENCODE lzo
   ,"last load date"  DATE         NULL ENCODE runlength
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY(serialnumber)
SORTKEY(serialnumber)
;
```

Comment: After responding to your second comment, I went and looked up all the compression encodings applied them to a new table, which looks remarkably similar to what you've posted. New table is 23GB. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Redshift should do the compression automatically by default. I really do not know why they leave it up to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you ran into this magical issue.

Redshift has 1 MB data blocks and because it is columnar all the columns get stored separately. Now let's say you have 10 columns in your table, so the first incoming record takes 10 MB (1 MB * 10 columns). Now based on the distkey you have chosen and the cardinality of this field, Redshift may or may not store the next values for each column in the same block where the first record went. If it decides to store all the columns in new blocks, it means your second record is also worth 10 MB. So, 130 million records have the potential to bloat till (130 m * 10)MB. I think your case is not this extreme, so few values are going to already allocated blocks while others are going to new memory blocks.

I suggest you try a different distkey as this one does not look like a good one.